# label appears from the GoPro SDK dependency

Tags: android, android-manifest, gopro

I have a string resource for an application label:

```
 <string name="app_name">My application</string>
```

My AndroidManifest.xml is classical:

```
<manifest.. >
 <application
        android:name="my.package"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:icon">
        <activity ...
```

I have GoPro SDK as a dependency. And on some devices (HTC U Play) my application is signed not as "My application", but as "GoPro SDK".

I have figured out that GoPro SDK valuses are realy containing resource:

```
<string name="app_name">GoPro SDK</string>
```

GoPro SDK is an **.arr** archive.

How to fix it without renaming of the variable **app_name**?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add to application tag the following attribute:

```
<application
    tools:replace="label, icon"/>
```

also I found that some of activities may contain label without `tools:replace="label"`

```
<activity android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

Just remove `label` from activities or add `tools:replace="label"` attribute